# Financial Time Series data normalization

Tags: keras, r, time-series, normalization

I'm using Keras in R to predict financial time series. It's easy to normalize price, simply compute returns or log returns, usually it's enough. I want to use Goldman Sachs Financial Conditions Index and MSCI World Index to predict other securitites and I want to use levels and their returns or first differences.  I think that using minmax or z-score normalization is not appropriate because series distribution will change. So, the question is how to normalize nonstationary time series data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-score normalization, as you have already guessed, cannot deal well with non-stationary time series since the mean and standard deviation of the time series vary over time.

Min-max and another commonly used normalization in stationary data, the decimal scaling normalization depend on knowing the maximum values of a time series.

The most commonly used method for data normalization of non-stationary time series  is the sliding window approach (J. Lin and E. Keogh, 2004, Finding or not finding rules in time series). In short:

> The basic idea of this approach is that, instead of considering the
>   complete time series for normalization, it divides the data
>   into sliding windows of length ω, extracts statistical
>   properties from it considering only a fraction of ω
>   consecutive time series values (H. Li and S. Lee, 2009, Mining frequent itemsets over data streams using efficient window sliding techniques, Expert Syst. Appl., v. 36, n.
>   2, p. 1466-1477. J.C. Hull, 2005), and normalizes each
>   window considering only these statistical properties. The
>   rationale behind this approach is that decisions are usually
>   based on recent data.
>   (...)
>   The sliding window technique has the
>   advantage of always normalizing data in the desired range.
>   However, it has a drawback of assuming that the time series
>   volatility is uniform, which is not true in many phenomena

Another more advanced and less used (so far) is [Adaptive Normalization](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gisele_Pappa/publication/221532708_Adaptive_Normalization_A_novel_data_normalization_approach_for_non-stationary_time_series/links/0c96051cc596087da6000000/Adaptive-Normalization-A-novel-data-normalization-approach-for-non-stationary-time-series.pdf)

> can be divided into three stages: (i)
>   transforming the non-stationary time series into a stationary
>   sequence, which creates a sequence of disjoint sliding
>   windows (that do not overlap); (ii) outlier removal; (iii) data
>   normalization itself.

Check the link on Adaptive Normalization and all its references, there is relevant information in there.